# A Soft Problem: Application of Stochastic Differential Equations in Hilbert Space Beyond HJM Interest Rate Model

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic

I am reading books on stochastic differential equations (SDE) in Hilbert spaces. It seems that every book just discusses HJM interest rate model as an application when  discussing financial applications. May I ask what other financial applications SDE in Hilbert spaces have, in particular, recently please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Emma Thank you so much!! Indeed, I just studied the first book you mentioned and some other related reference, and that's why I come up with this problem.